# ¿Cómo puedo sacar el subtotal de un precio por la cantidad?

Tags: php, mysql

En un CRUD que estoy haciendo en PHP y mysql, tengo las columnas "Precio_Unitario" y "Cantidad" y me gustaría saber cómo puedo mostrar en una tercera tabla "Subtotal" el resultado de multiplicar el precio por la cantidad.

Anteriormente intenté hacer esto (multiplicar cantidad por precio y darle un alias para luego hacer Echo de ese alias en la tabla):

```
$sql="SELECT id, descripcion, unidad, cantidad, precio_unitario, cantidad * precio_unitario AS subtotal FROM presupuesto";
$query=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

Y los mostraba en el CRUD así:

```html
<tbody>
    <?php 
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row['id'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $row['descripcion'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $row['unidad'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $row['cantidad'] ?></th>
        <th>$<?php echo number_format($row['precio_unitario'], 2, '.', ','); ?></th>
        <th>$<?php echo number_format($row['subtotal'], 2, '.', ','); ?></th>
        <th><a href="actualizar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a></th>
        <th><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a></th>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    
</tbody>
```

El problema vino cuando quise sacar el total de esa columna e investigando creo que no puedo hacer cálculos con los alias, por lo que me toca reformular la forma en que saco el subtotal, pero en verdad he intentado un par de cosas y aún no lo logro.

Comment: Cómo intentaste sacar el total? no veo errores en tu código

Comment: `total` es una columna de tu tabla o una variable global?

Comment: lo intenté sacar con SUM(subtotal) pero no me funciona y leí por ahí que eso no funciona con alias

Comment: primero preguntas "cómo puedo sacar el subtotal" y luego "el problema vino cuando quise sacar el total", osea, quieres calcular el total de subtotales?

Comment: Si te trabas con las consultas MySQL hazlo todo con PHP e inicializa una variable `$total = 0;` antes del bucle, y dentro la pones así: `$total = $total + $row['subtotal'];` y una vez termine el bucle la muestras como quieras, por ejemplo:  `echo $total;`

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con variables, tendrías que inicializar una variable en 0 y en el bucle vas sumando los subtotales y al final haces un echo del total

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a los dos, sí me funcionó así <3